# Using Cell Value as a Worksheet Name in Formula

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-arrayformula

I wanted to use a cell's content as a sheet name, i.e.

| *A1* | *A2* | *A3* | *A4* |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| South | North | East | West |

and use the cell values (South, North, East, West) to reference cells from sheets called South, North, East, West like this:

```
=South!A1  
=North!A1  
etc. . .
```

I wanted to use this to count all instances of TRUE in column A. My current implementation was inspired by a [solution for Microsoft Excel](https://excelribbon.tips.net/T006069_Using_a_Cell_Value_as_a_Worksheet_Name_in_a_Formula.html) and uses the *INDIRECT()* function, but it doesn't seem to work for Google Sheets:

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(SUM(IF(INDIRECT(A1)!$A:$A = TRUE, 1, 0)))
```

Comment: Welcome to [Web Applications Stack Exchange](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/tour).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `indirect()` function expects a text string that resolves into a *range* reference, so you will need to use string concatenation, like this:

`=arrayformula( sum( indirect(A1 & "!A:A") + 0 ) )`

The `if()` is a bit superfluous here and can be omitted provided that you coerce Boolean values `true`/`false` to integers `1`/`0` as shown.